# gnuploting curve filled maps

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I want to get a map using gnuplot like map1.
There are my code and part of the data.When I do set  `set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d/%h"` ``` set xdata time``set format x "%m/%d" ```, it responded error in map2. I didn't know how to figure out it. Hope you can help me.

```
set style data lines
set style fill solid 1.00 noborder
set boxwidth 0.75 absolute 
unset ylabel
unset xlabel
unset xtics
set origin 0.050, 0.300
unset ylabel
#set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d/%h"
#set xdata time
#set format x "%m/%d"
set ytics nomirror font ",11"
set style increment default
set xtics nomirror norangelimit
set ytics 0,80,320
set size 0.9,0.9
set size ratio 0.4
unset key
plot [][0:320]'average.shijiazhua.ch36km.2020.NSA_total.ts' using 1:(0):(\$2) w filledcu axis x1y1 lc rgb "#EF476F" t "Power",\
          '' using 1:(\$2):(\$2+\$3) w filledcu  lc rgb "#8ac926" t "Industry",\
          '' using 1:(\$2+\$3):(\$2+\$3+\$4) w filledcu  lc rgb "#1982c4" t "Agriculture",\
          '' using 1:(\$2+\$3+\$4):(\$2+\$3+\$4+\$5) w filledcu  t "Residential",\
          '' using 1:(\$2+\$3+\$4+\$5):(\$2+\$3+\$4+\$5+\$6) w filledcu lc rgb "#c77dff" t "Transportation"
```

Data:

```
2020050500   34.92820   33.47148   69.01359    8.37408   36.82053
2020050501   34.14014   31.02070   68.22377    8.03866   35.97493
2020050502   32.93465   28.59794   66.69872    7.79872   34.76229
2020050503   31.56261   26.31655   64.97402    7.60045   33.42817
2020050504   29.55138   23.19680   61.65179    7.20578   31.10942
2020050505   28.45511   21.41614   60.70938    7.15501   29.97279
2020050506   28.78439   21.22073   63.38977    7.55193   30.63113
2020050507   28.32452   20.49873   64.72398    7.80252   30.85250
2020050508   25.49913   18.48231   60.84341    7.72398   29.33283
2020050509   19.03617   14.95413   49.02392    7.68153   23.93946
2020050510   14.25507   12.42948   39.15635    7.59906   19.45655
2020050511   11.56549   10.86627   33.26527    7.08790   16.58210
2020050512   10.40714   10.28374   30.64410    6.73005   15.23610
2020050513    9.99347   10.23459   30.32369    6.50979   15.00718
2020050514    9.77059   10.03319   30.06268    6.34308   14.90386
2020050515    9.46511    9.68426   28.68079    6.15453   14.22397
2020050516    9.12669    9.52622   27.02652    6.12770   13.46605
2020050517    8.94960    9.70764   26.01473    6.21285   12.75945
2020050518    8.30828    9.19368   23.64348    5.64860   11.42775
2020050519    6.98423    7.77228   19.39676    4.56069    9.39085
2020050520    5.81946    6.37644   15.79359    3.60976    7.73696
2020050521    5.36498    5.64128   14.26162    3.11704    7.00662
2020050522    5.18471    5.20392   13.71013    2.84699    6.70183
2020050523    4.96575    4.67512   13.20869    2.56693    6.34549
2020050600    4.80342    4.29339   12.99936    2.36875    6.11740
2020050601    4.57129    3.82130   12.45918    2.13018    5.80136
2020050602    4.62375    3.69038   12.84608    2.07090    5.95253
2020050603    4.89624    3.78565   13.95552    2.15729    6.42439
2020050604    5.11386    3.70182   14.69319    2.17235    6.70257
2020050605    5.32001    3.66094   15.21974    2.19411    6.86478
2020050606    5.51991    3.87873   15.74852    2.32875    7.07490
2020050607    5.67472    4.34660   16.24980    2.56207    7.47552
2020050608    7.11860    7.23675   22.40004    3.77179   10.82728
2020050609    7.91739    8.27180   24.90193    4.18627   12.04413
2020050610    8.40120    8.44643   25.63029    4.42067   12.51950
2020050611    8.78894    8.91031   26.46757    4.79258   13.22055
2020050612    8.75023    9.05808   25.82002    5.18174   13.31731
2020050613    8.69377    9.18953   25.18435    5.58854   13.35642
2020050614    8.67938    9.23050   24.79873    5.81155   13.34736
2020050615    8.61072    9.05110   24.20865    5.83554   13.13042
2020050616    8.61898    9.38255   24.24635    6.02599   13.15560
2020050617    9.88121   12.44088   28.35582    7.22637   15.13754
2020050618   13.03567   17.87587   35.27399    8.69368   18.69806
2020050619   17.21906   22.73761   41.73368    9.50554   22.38980
2020050620   22.06430   26.93686   48.36322   10.13785   26.27978
2020050621   27.02551   30.15065   54.72841   10.65425   30.01287
2020050622   29.04600   30.14368   57.09066   10.54669   31.39031
2020050623   28.72626   28.07003   56.50034   10.02480   30.99561
2020050700   28.97064   26.99266   57.29614    9.75325   31.34316
2020050701   29.37847   26.09241   57.38815    9.41128   31.39288
2020050702   29.04029   23.62373   54.13726    8.71631   29.70628
2020050703   26.91615   19.50575   47.41990    7.68835   26.01030
2020050704   22.78487   15.26919   39.35748    6.38515   21.32836
2020050705   15.26723   10.62037   27.09076    5.20689   14.57554
2020050706    8.87406    7.55900   17.58181    4.93560    9.53557
2020050707    6.11438    6.48395   14.25941    5.27410    7.86598
2020050708    4.67842    5.50418   12.43140    5.45161    7.09094
2020050709    3.64316    4.24208   10.22776    5.41426    6.11685
2020050710    3.17714    3.64387    8.92585    5.55745    5.67752
2020050711    3.20047    3.70725    8.78954    5.71015    5.83647
2020050712    3.50073    4.00986    9.26960    5.64515    6.21379
2020050713    3.59172    4.10384    9.19951    5.44214    6.23010
2020050714    3.32714    3.86352    8.31776    4.95656    5.70188
2020050715    2.92304    3.50896    7.19465    4.30262    4.96345
2020050716    2.61181    3.36959    6.41498    3.78693    4.42651
2020050717    2.77914    4.12923    6.82416    3.69544    4.57126
2020050718    4.21519    6.94777    9.53290    4.03701    6.17134
2020050719    6.95361   11.13112   14.64627    4.72538    9.09068
2020050720   10.43964   15.30013   21.20108    5.65491   12.65777
2020050721   13.85205   18.44100   27.72278    6.57799   16.04925
2020050722   16.65494   20.41442   33.30551    7.37484   18.98996
2020050723   18.98237   21.99487   38.32611    8.08933   21.69509
2020050800   21.45151   23.63957   42.98992    8.55449   24.35935
```

[image: map1]
[image: map2]

Comment: The question is very unclear.  I copied your data and put it in a file called "gnupdata.txt".
Then I ran the command:
plot [][0:320]'gnupdata.txt' using 1:(0):($2) w filledcu axis x1y1 lc rgb "#EF476F" t "Power", '' using 1:($2):($2+$3) w filledcu  lc rgb "#8ac926" t "Industry", '' using 1:($2+$3):($2+$3+$4) w filledcu  lc rgb "#1982c4" t "Agriculture", '' using 1:($2+$3+$4):($2+$3+$4+$5) w filledcu  t "Residential", '' using 1:($2+$3+$4+$5):($2+$3+$4+$5+$6) w filledcu lc rgb "#c77dff" t "Transportation"

It worked perfectly without warnings.

Comment: @Fabrizio Did you get the map like map1?

Comment: I get a plot that is different from the one you put in the image.

Comment: @Fabrizio Did you add any code based on the code I supported? I think it needs to add xrange  when use `set timefmt`?

Comment: I copy all your code and I adjusted only the "plot" line.  The plot line is the one I put in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this question is fully answered.
I cleaned up your code a little. I don't know why you used `\$2`. If you put the below code into a text file and load this text file to gnuplot it should work.

**Edit:** to make the plot command a bit shorter and more clear you can:

1. define a function `myTime(col) = timecolumn(col,myTimeFmt)`
2. instead of filling the area between 2 curves, fill the area between a curve and the x-axis, but start with the upper curve.
3. why do you `unset key`? don't you want a legend?

**Code:**

```
### filledcurves and time data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
2020050500   34.92820   33.47148   69.01359    8.37408   36.82053
2020050501   34.14014   31.02070   68.22377    8.03866   35.97493
2020050502   32.93465   28.59794   66.69872    7.79872   34.76229
2020050503   31.56261   26.31655   64.97402    7.60045   33.42817
2020050504   29.55138   23.19680   61.65179    7.20578   31.10942
2020050505   28.45511   21.41614   60.70938    7.15501   29.97279
2020050506   28.78439   21.22073   63.38977    7.55193   30.63113
2020050507   28.32452   20.49873   64.72398    7.80252   30.85250
2020050508   25.49913   18.48231   60.84341    7.72398   29.33283
2020050509   19.03617   14.95413   49.02392    7.68153   23.93946
2020050510   14.25507   12.42948   39.15635    7.59906   19.45655
2020050511   11.56549   10.86627   33.26527    7.08790   16.58210
2020050512   10.40714   10.28374   30.64410    6.73005   15.23610
2020050513    9.99347   10.23459   30.32369    6.50979   15.00718
2020050514    9.77059   10.03319   30.06268    6.34308   14.90386
2020050515    9.46511    9.68426   28.68079    6.15453   14.22397
2020050516    9.12669    9.52622   27.02652    6.12770   13.46605
2020050517    8.94960    9.70764   26.01473    6.21285   12.75945
2020050518    8.30828    9.19368   23.64348    5.64860   11.42775
2020050519    6.98423    7.77228   19.39676    4.56069    9.39085
2020050520    5.81946    6.37644   15.79359    3.60976    7.73696
2020050521    5.36498    5.64128   14.26162    3.11704    7.00662
2020050522    5.18471    5.20392   13.71013    2.84699    6.70183
2020050523    4.96575    4.67512   13.20869    2.56693    6.34549
2020050600    4.80342    4.29339   12.99936    2.36875    6.11740
2020050601    4.57129    3.82130   12.45918    2.13018    5.80136
2020050602    4.62375    3.69038   12.84608    2.07090    5.95253
2020050603    4.89624    3.78565   13.95552    2.15729    6.42439
2020050604    5.11386    3.70182   14.69319    2.17235    6.70257
2020050605    5.32001    3.66094   15.21974    2.19411    6.86478
2020050606    5.51991    3.87873   15.74852    2.32875    7.07490
2020050607    5.67472    4.34660   16.24980    2.56207    7.47552
2020050608    7.11860    7.23675   22.40004    3.77179   10.82728
2020050609    7.91739    8.27180   24.90193    4.18627   12.04413
2020050610    8.40120    8.44643   25.63029    4.42067   12.51950
2020050611    8.78894    8.91031   26.46757    4.79258   13.22055
2020050612    8.75023    9.05808   25.82002    5.18174   13.31731
2020050613    8.69377    9.18953   25.18435    5.58854   13.35642
2020050614    8.67938    9.23050   24.79873    5.81155   13.34736
2020050615    8.61072    9.05110   24.20865    5.83554   13.13042
2020050616    8.61898    9.38255   24.24635    6.02599   13.15560
2020050617    9.88121   12.44088   28.35582    7.22637   15.13754
2020050618   13.03567   17.87587   35.27399    8.69368   18.69806
2020050619   17.21906   22.73761   41.73368    9.50554   22.38980
2020050620   22.06430   26.93686   48.36322   10.13785   26.27978
2020050621   27.02551   30.15065   54.72841   10.65425   30.01287
2020050622   29.04600   30.14368   57.09066   10.54669   31.39031
2020050623   28.72626   28.07003   56.50034   10.02480   30.99561
2020050700   28.97064   26.99266   57.29614    9.75325   31.34316
2020050701   29.37847   26.09241   57.38815    9.41128   31.39288
2020050702   29.04029   23.62373   54.13726    8.71631   29.70628
2020050703   26.91615   19.50575   47.41990    7.68835   26.01030
2020050704   22.78487   15.26919   39.35748    6.38515   21.32836
2020050705   15.26723   10.62037   27.09076    5.20689   14.57554
2020050706    8.87406    7.55900   17.58181    4.93560    9.53557
2020050707    6.11438    6.48395   14.25941    5.27410    7.86598
2020050708    4.67842    5.50418   12.43140    5.45161    7.09094
2020050709    3.64316    4.24208   10.22776    5.41426    6.11685
2020050710    3.17714    3.64387    8.92585    5.55745    5.67752
2020050711    3.20047    3.70725    8.78954    5.71015    5.83647
2020050712    3.50073    4.00986    9.26960    5.64515    6.21379
2020050713    3.59172    4.10384    9.19951    5.44214    6.23010
2020050714    3.32714    3.86352    8.31776    4.95656    5.70188
2020050715    2.92304    3.50896    7.19465    4.30262    4.96345
2020050716    2.61181    3.36959    6.41498    3.78693    4.42651
2020050717    2.77914    4.12923    6.82416    3.69544    4.57126
2020050718    4.21519    6.94777    9.53290    4.03701    6.17134
2020050719    6.95361   11.13112   14.64627    4.72538    9.09068
2020050720   10.43964   15.30013   21.20108    5.65491   12.65777
2020050721   13.85205   18.44100   27.72278    6.57799   16.04925
2020050722   16.65494   20.41442   33.30551    7.37484   18.98996
2020050723   18.98237   21.99487   38.32611    8.08933   21.69509
2020050800   21.45151   23.63957   42.98992    8.55449   24.35935
EOD

set size 0.9,0.9
set size ratio 0.4

unset xlabel
unset xtics
set xtics nomirror norangelimit
unset ylabel
set ytics nomirror font ",11"
set ytics 0,80,320

myTimeFmt = "%Y%m%d%H"
set format x "%m/%d\n%H:%M" time

set style data lines
set style fill solid 1.00 noborder
set style increment default

myTime(col) = timecolumn(col,myTimeFmt)
plot [][0:320] \
    $Data u (myTime(1)):($2+$3+$4+$5+$6) w filledcu x1 lc rgb "#c77dff" t "Transportation", \
    '' u (myTime(1)):($2+$3+$4+$5) w filledcu x1 t "Residential",\
    '' u (myTime(1)):($2+$3+$4) w filledcu x1 lc rgb "#1982c4" t "Agriculture",\
    '' u (myTime(1)):($2+$3) w filledcu x1 lc rgb "#8ac926" t "Industry",\
    '' u (myTime(1)):($2) w filledcu x1 lc rgb "#EF476F" t "Power"    
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]